# Can I (dynamically) specify displayed columns using URL for list?

Tags: list-view, column, url

I know how to create a URL using defined (i.e. static named) views for a list/lib. I know that a URL can be created to specify filtering and sorting on a column of a view.

But can a URL itself actually specify which list columns to display?

This is done without creating a named view to specify the display of a list's columns and then referencing it in a URL. I know that a list's static/named view is specified in an ASPX file that itself specifies what columns are displayed, but can the URL basically modify & override that specification, and why can't a list be displayed without the use of an ASPX file?  I am aware of the practical length limitation of the URL in SP (400 chars?) but I only want to indicate the display of 5 columns of the list.

The URL is generated from a web application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your options include preliminarily creating several views for common combinations of columns, or create a personal list view upon navigation, then navigate to it afterwards.

Depending on your version, I guess you could create a view with all fields in SharePoint Designer and using javascript to show/hide fields based on the query strings.

Other than that, you'd be getting into creating your own SharePoint views as complete custom views/tables for SharePoint list data--which wouldn't include much of the integration, menus, actions, etc.

Comment: So I can work off a named view, say the default, automatically created "All Documents" view, which would have all the ASP-XML markup to build the chrome (I get the need for that), and I can modify the columns to remove or to add using the URL query string? If that's so, I only need to learn (1) what columns are defined for the view, (2) the syntax to add columns in the lib that are not present in the view, and (3) the syntax to omit columns in the view. And as a bonus, the syntax of the query string to specify a column (re-)order of that on-the-fly modified view.

Comment: Yeah, what I'd do is: use `display:none` on the columns as static css , then load your javascript to grab the query string, and one by one you can unhide the columns based on the query string values